# How do I turn a group of curves 3D?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Hello! I am having some trouble turning a group of curves to 3D from 2D. Is there any way so I don't need to turn them one by one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select all the curves, put your cursor over the 3D button and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>